# MySQL select result inside JS function

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I found a simple *JS* script that works as a chatbot. 
in the script itself the results of lastUserMessage are predefined inline like

```
if (lastUserMessage === 'name') {
   botMessage = 'My name is ' + botName;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is if the *JS* to search for **lastUserMessage** within a db and to provide **botMessage** from there.

I am sure it should't be that hard, but I cant figure out how to do it.

**Here is the *JS* code:**

```
nlp = window.nlp_compromise;
var messages = [], //array that hold the record of each string in chat
  lastUserMessage = "", //keeps track of the most recent input string from the user
  botMessage = "", //var keeps track of what the chatbot is going to say
  botName = 'Bot Name', //name of the chatbot
  talking = true; //when false the speach function doesn't work

//edit this function to change what the chatbot says
function chatbotResponse() {
  talking = true;
  botMessage = "Ops... didn't get this"; //the default message

  if (lastUserMessage === 'name') {
    botMessage = 'My name is ' + botName;
  }

}

//this runs each time enter is pressed.
//It controls the overall input and output
function newEntry() {
  //if the message from the user isn't empty then run 
  if (document.getElementById("chatbox").value != "") {
    //pulls the value from the chatbox ands sets it to lastUserMessage
    lastUserMessage = document.getElementById("chatbox").value;
    //sets the chat box to be clear
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value = "";
    //adds the value of the chatbox to the array messages
    messages.push(lastUserMessage);
    //Speech(lastUserMessage);  //says what the user typed outloud
    //sets the variable botMessage in response to lastUserMessage
    chatbotResponse();
    //add the chatbot's name and message to the array messages
    messages.push("<b>" + botName + ":</b> " + botMessage);
    // says the message using the text to speech function written below
    Speech(botMessage);
    //outputs the last few array elements of messages to html
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      if (messages[messages.length - i])
        document.getElementById("chatlog" + i).innerHTML = messages[messages.length - i];
    }
  }
}

//runs the keypress() function when a key is pressed
document.onkeypress = keyPress;
//if the key pressed is 'enter' runs the function newEntry()
function keyPress(e) {
  var x = e || window.event;
  var key = (x.keyCode || x.which);
  if (key == 13 || key == 3) {
    //runs this function when enter is pressed
    newEntry();
  }
  if (key == 38) {
    console.log('hi')
      //document.getElementById("chatbox").value = lastUserMessage;
  }
}

//clears the placeholder text ion the chatbox
//this function is set to run when the users brings focus to the chatbox, by clicking on it
function placeHolder() {
  document.getElementById("chatbox").placeholder = "";
}
```

**Here is the HTML code**

```
<div id='bodybox'>
  <div id='chatborder'>
    <p id="chatlog2" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="chatlog1" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
    <input type="text" name="chat" id="chatbox" placeholder="Hi there! Type here to talk to me." onfocus="placeHolder()">
  </div>
```

**What need to happen?**

> Ideally, the script should take the values "**lastUserMessage**" and 
>   "**botMessage**" from a db that has 2 columns "**lastUserMessage**" and 
>   "**botMessage**".

**What I tried to to do is following Ghost's comment below... but didn't work.**

```
    nlp = window.nlp_compromise;
var messages = [], //array that hold the record of each string in chat
  lastUserMessage = "", //keeps track of the most recent input string from the user
  botMessage = "", //var keeps track of what the chatbot is going to say
  botName = 'Bot Name', //name of the chatbot
  talking = true; //when false the speach function doesn't work

//edit this function to change what the chatbot says
function chatbotResponse() {
  talking = true;
  botMessage = "Ops... didn't get this"; //the default message

      $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'db_query.php',         
  data: "lastUserMessag=lastUserMessag", 
  dataType: 'json',                 
  success: function(data)          
  {
    var lastUserMessage_db = data[0]; 
    var botMessage_db= data[1];

if (lastUserMessage === lastUserMessage_db) {
    botMessage = botMessage_db;
  }
  } 
});

}

//this runs each time enter is pressed.
//It controls the overall input and output
function newEntry() {
  //if the message from the user isn't empty then run 
  if (document.getElementById("chatbox").value != "") {
    //pulls the value from the chatbox ands sets it to lastUserMessage
    lastUserMessage = document.getElementById("chatbox").value;
    //sets the chat box to be clear
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value = "";
    //adds the value of the chatbox to the array messages
    messages.push(lastUserMessage);
    //Speech(lastUserMessage);  //says what the user typed outloud
    //sets the variable botMessage in response to lastUserMessage
    chatbotResponse();
    //add the chatbot's name and message to the array messages
    messages.push("<b>" + botName + ":</b> " + botMessage);
    // says the message using the text to speech function written below
    Speech(botMessage);
    //outputs the last few array elements of messages to html
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      if (messages[messages.length - i])
        document.getElementById("chatlog" + i).innerHTML = messages[messages.length - i];
    }
  }
}

//runs the keypress() function when a key is pressed
document.onkeypress = keyPress;
//if the key pressed is 'enter' runs the function newEntry()
function keyPress(e) {
  var x = e || window.event;
  var key = (x.keyCode || x.which);
  if (key == 13 || key == 3) {
    //runs this function when enter is pressed
    newEntry();
  }
  if (key == 38) {
    console.log('hi')
      //document.getElementById("chatbox").value = lastUserMessage;
  }
}

//clears the placeholder text ion the chatbox
//this function is set to run when the users brings focus to the chatbox, by clicking on it
function placeHolder() {
  document.getElementById("chatbox").placeholder = "";
}
```

**And in DB_query.php I have**

```
$p = $_GET['lastUserMessag']; 
      $query=mysql_query("SELECT lastUserMessag, botMessage FROM `aiml` WHERE lastUserMessag='$p'");
      $array = mysql_fetch_row($query);  
    echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: What server is this running on?

Comment: I suppose you're using client-side JS so what does the server-side app look like? Client-side JS executes HTTP requests to a server and the server looks into the database with some query. I cannot see where JS issues MySQL queries directly.

Comment: It is on a windows server. The JS does not issues MySQL queries.... I believe this is what I need to happen.

Comment: You would need to GET/POST your server that accesses the MySQL database. Otherwise you could use local storage although I’m not sure that’s what you want and if all browsers support it. Read this: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage

Comment: So you want SO users to write the server-side code for you? Did you try to search and see how you can achieve that?

Comment: Of course I have searched, otherwise I wouldn't ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is how I make it work with Stamos' help**

```js
nlp = window.nlp_compromise;

var messages = [], //array that hold the record of each string in chat
  lastUserMessage = "", //keeps track of the most recent input string from the user
  botMessage = "", //var keeps track of what the chatbot is going to say
  botName = 'Bot Name', //name of the chatbot
  talking = true; //when false the speach function doesn't work
//

//****************************************************************
//edit this function to change what the chatbot says
function chatbotResponse() {
  talking = true;
  botMessage = "Sorry, Didnt get that"; //the default message

  $.ajax({
    url: "appi.php?lastUserMessage=" + lastUserMessage,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {

      var obj = JSON.parse(data);

      if (lastUserMessage === obj.lastUserMessage) {
        botMessage = obj.botMessage;
      }
    }
  });

}

//****************************************************************

//this runs each time enter is pressed.
//It controls the overall input and output
function newEntry() {
  //if the message from the user isn't empty then run 
  if (document.getElementById("chatbox").value != "") {
    //pulls the value from the chatbox ands sets it to lastUserMessage
    lastUserMessage = document.getElementById("chatbox").value;
    //sets the chat box to be clear
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value = "";
    //adds the value of the chatbox to the array messages
    messages.push(lastUserMessage);
    //Speech(lastUserMessage);  //says what the user typed outloud
    //sets the variable botMessage in response to lastUserMessage
    chatbotResponse();
    //add the chatbot's name and message to the array messages
    messages.push("<b>" + botName + ":</b> " + botMessage);
    // says the message using the text to speech function written below
    Speech(botMessage);
    //outputs the last few array elements of messages to html
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      if (messages[messages.length - i])
        document.getElementById("chatlog" + i).innerHTML = messages[messages.length - i];
    }
  }
}

//text to Speech
//https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk-Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API
function Speech(say) {
  //if ('speechSynthesis' in window && talking) {
  //  var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(say);
  //msg.voice = voices[10]; // Note: some voices don't support altering params
  //msg.voiceURI = 'native';
  //utterance.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
  //utterance.rate = 0.1; // 0.1 to 10
  //utterance.pitch = 1; //0 to 2
  //utterance.text = 'Hello World';
  //utterance.lang = 'en-US';
  // speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
  // }
}

//runs the keypress() function when a key is pressed
document.onkeypress = keyPress;
//if the key pressed is 'enter' runs the function newEntry()
function keyPress(e) {
  var x = e || window.event;
  var key = (x.keyCode || x.which);
  if (key == 13 || key == 3) {
    //runs this function when enter is pressed
    newEntry();
  }
  if (key == 38) {
    console.log('hi')
    //document.getElementById("chatbox").value = lastUserMessage;
  }
}

//clears the placeholder text ion the chatbox
//this function is set to run when the users brings focus to the chatbox, by clicking on it
function placeHolder() {
  document.getElementById("chatbox").placeholder = "";
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#bodybox {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 550px;
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#chatborder {
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #f6f9f6;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.chatlog {
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
}

#chatbox {
  font: 17px arial, sans-serif;
  //height: 22px;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
}

pre {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</script>
<div id='bodybox'>
  <h1>Virtual Assistant</h1>
  <div id='chatborder' class="form-group">
    <p id="chatlog7" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="chatlog6" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="chatlog5" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="chatlog4" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="chatlog3" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="chatlog2" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="chatlog1" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
    <input type="text" name="chat" id="chatbox" placeholder="Hi there! Type here to talk to me." onfocus="placeHolder()" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

**and in the appi.php I have this code**

> ```
> $p = $_GET['lastUserMessage'];
> //open connection to mysql db
> $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
>
> //fetch table rows from mysql db
> $sql = "select lastUserMessage, botMessage FROM `table_name` WHERE lastUserMessage='$p'";
> $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
>
> //create an array
>
> $emparray = $array;
> while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
> {
>     $emparray = $row;
> }
> echo json_encode($emparray);
>
> //close the db connection
> mysqli_close($connection);
> ```

Answer (score 6):

The Javascript you are executing currently runs in the browser but is not connected to any Database that you could fetch data from.

To do so you'd have to send a POST or GET request to your backend server (assuming you have one) that, I assume, is written in JS, using NodeJS.

Note that you should ***NEVER*** give the user access (e.g. connect the database to the code you are using right now, which executes in a browser) to said database as they are then able to do whatever they want with it.

If you want to look into [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and how to handle requests, I suggest you look into [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) and [this great MySQL + NodeJS tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp) on W3Schools depending on your level of expertise

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to do it... but for some reason it doesn't want to trigger the request to the database

Comment: If using NodeJS, instead of AJAX request, I would suggest using websocket

Comment: Suggesting `ExpressJS` for this is overkill. If you only want to access database and return the data to the client, why would you use a full-featured framework? Or any framework at all? It may be easier to start, but in my opinion it's not a good way to learn.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript runs in the Client's browser.  MySQL runs in the Server.  So, something else is needed to connect them.

I use PHP and AJAX as the conduit between them.  JS issues an AJAX call.  (Note:  "A" stands for "Asynchronous".)  Then JS gets the results via a "callback".  Meanwhile, the target of the AJAX 'call' is a PHP program (or Java or VB or ...) which connects to the database (MySQL) and performs the `SELECT` and builds the JSON to deliver back to JS.

Answer (score 1):

have you confirmed that the `db_query.php` works?

Try to use POSTMAN or Broswer like Chrome to hit the url ex. `localhost/db_query.php` or the correct one and see if you get the result you are expecting.

If you get the expected result then something is wrong with you JavaScript.

$.ajax is asynchronous so it will be called and the javascript execution will continue.

I try explain it. You call `chatbotResponse()` witch does a `$.ajax` call that on `success` sets the data

```
var lastUserMessage_db = data[0]; 
var botMessage_db= data[1];
```

BUT $.ajax is asynchronous so javascript execution will continue SO this javascript code will run before success is called

```
    //add the chatbot's name and message to the array messages
    messages.push("<b>" + botName + ":</b> " + botMessage);
    // says the message using the text to speech function written below
    Speech(botMessage);
    //outputs the last few array elements of messages to html
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      if (messages[messages.length - i])
        document.getElementById("chatlog" + i).innerHTML = messages[messages.length - i];
    }
```

so the problem is that the above code will run before you get the `lastUserMessage` from `db_query.php`

**Solution**

Easy solution is change ajax to synchronous call `async:false`, this is not best practice.

```
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'db_query.php?lastUserMessage='+lastUserMessage,         
  type: "GET",
  async: false,               
  success: function(data)          
  {
    var lastUserMessage_db = data[0]; 
    var botMessage_db= data[1];

if (lastUserMessage === lastUserMessage_db) {
    botMessage = botMessage_db;
  }
  } 
});
```

Better way is to utilize the success callback

Example:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'db_query.php?lastUserMessage='+lastUserMessage,         
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        var lastUserMessage_db = data[0];
        var botMessage_db = data[1];

        if (lastUserMessage === lastUserMessage_db) {
          botMessage = botMessage_db;
        }

        //add the chatbot's name and message to the array messages
        messages.push("<b>" + botName + ":</b> " + botMessage);
        // says the message using the text to speech function written below
        Speech(botMessage);
        //outputs the last few array elements of messages to html
        for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
          if (messages[messages.length - i])
            document.getElementById("chatlog" + i).innerHTML = messages[messages.length - i];
        }

      }
    });
```

Comment: I have tried using both examples, but for some reason it doesn't want to execute the query. When I try to execute db_query.php it does return both lastUserMessage and botMessage. One thing that I am thinking is: How does the Ajax understand if it should use POST or GET? or dataType: 'json' is enough? in the db_query.php I use $p = $_GET['lastUserMessage']; to get the value from the url.

Comment: Fixed ajax calls check it out.

Comment: Please check your code you have some possible typos. I would suggest to use some developer tools like chromes to debug your code.

Comment: I had one typo in lastUserMessag=lastUserMessag...fixed. Tried the new code... but still doesn't work.

Comment: one other thing that I have noticed is that when I try to alert the lastUserMessage_db or botMessage_db inside the ajax, it returns only the first letter

Comment: And a little bit more on the topic. I have tried to execute the .ajax only hard-coding the lastUserMessage... and still receive only one character when I try to alert the result alert(botMessage_db);

Comment: and if I alert the data within the whole script I am getting the json_encode($array); correctly, something like this ["name","My name is bot"], so it seems to me that there is something wrong with this piece............ if (lastUserMessage === lastUserMessage_db) {
    botMessage = botMessage_db;
  }

Comment: Yes correct, one letter is expected when you do `string[0]`. your data is a string so when you do `data[0]` it will show the first letter. You will have to `var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);` and then try to `alert` `dataObj`. 
For me you should learn to debug javascript. it will help you 1000%. I use chrome dev tools check it out [Pause Your Code With Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints), If you put a break point in success you will be able to see what `data` has on mouse hover. also you can use console to run code on the fly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159740/discussion-between-stamos-and-lstoilov).